# How to put a Drawer on the left side of a TabBar?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have a TabBar on the top of my app and I want to put a Drawer on the same place but all the way on the left. I would prefer it if the Drawer didn't move as I scrolled right on my TabBar.

```
return DefaultTabController(
      length: 6,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 40, 0, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black,
                    unselectedLabelColor: kGrey1,
                    unselectedLabelStyle: kNonActiveTabStyle,
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                    labelStyle: kActiveTabStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 25.0),
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "All"),
                      Tab(text: "Category"),
                      Tab(text: "Lunch"),
                      Tab(text: "Athletics"),
                      Tab(text: "Dates"),
                      Tab(text: "About"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            AllTabView(),
            Cate(),
            Lunch(),
            Sports(),
            Dates(),
            About(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf1DM.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create something custom like this:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu)),
    Expanded(
      child: TabBar(
        labelColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        isScrollable: true,
        indicatorColor: Colors.black,
        tabs: [
          Tab(text: "All"),
          Tab(text: "Category"),
          Tab(text: "Lunch"),
          Tab(text: "Athletics"),
          Tab(text: "Dates"),
          Tab(text: "About"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

and use a globalKey.

```dart
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: 6,
    child: Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),...
```

Full Code:

```dart
// @dart=2.9
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'includingfiles/About.dart';
import 'includingfiles/Dates.dart';
import 'includingfiles/constant/constants.dart';
import 'includingfiles/categories.dart';
import 'includingfiles/homepage/homepages.dart';
import 'includingfiles/liveSports.dart';
import 'includingfiles/lunch.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 6,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Item 1'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 40, 0, 0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.menu)),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.black,
                      unselectedLabelColor: kGrey1,
                      unselectedLabelStyle: kNonActiveTabStyle,
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                      labelStyle: kActiveTabStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 25.0),
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(text: "All"),
                        Tab(text: "Category"),
                        Tab(text: "Lunch"),
                        Tab(text: "Athletics"),
                        Tab(text: "Dates"),
                        Tab(text: "About"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            AllTabView(),
            Cate(),
            Lunch(),
            Sports(),
            Dates(),
            About(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the Scaffold? I didn't put it yet and it tells me:

The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: openDrawer()

Comment: You have already added scaffold, just use the global key,  key: _scaffoldKey.

Comment: I mean like the second part of the second code you put. I don’t know where to paste it in. I can’t just put it outside of any class. It creates an error.

Comment: Yea it still doesn't work. The full code is here: https://pastebin.com/82xkscDJ
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: openDrawer()

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I deleted the other question.